# Build String depending on Column values [Oracle SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
   ID | UNIT|   CODE
    2 |  A  |   bit0
    2 |  A  |   bit2
    1 |  B  |   bit2
    2 |  B  |   bit7
    1 |  B  |   bit5
    1 |  C  |   bit7
```

I wonder how can I group the bits depending on the ID and UNIT? For example, the output for the source table above would be:

```
ID|UNIT|  CODE
2 | A  |00000101
1 | B  |00100100
1 | C  |10000000
2 | B  |10000000
```

is a  `CASE` statement + concatenating 1's and 0's the best option here? I really don't think so but that's the only solution I can find at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use the `bit_or` aggregation function in MySQL, but it is not available in Oracle.

If you never have more than one bit set, you could do

```
select id, unit,
       sum(case when code = 'bit0' then 1
                when code = 'bit1' then 2
                when code = 'bit2' then 4
                when code = 'bit3' then 8
                when code = 'bit4' then 16
                when code = 'bit5' then 32
                when code = 'bit6' then 64
                when code = 'bit7' then 128
                else 0
            end)
from table t
group by id, unit;
```

But that's not really a satisfying answer.

Instead, you need to spread the values out, aggregate, and bring them back.  Here is a method where the result is a string:

```
select id, unit,
       (max(case when code = 'bit0' then 1 else 0 end) ||
        max(case when code = 'bit1' then 1 else 0 end) ||
        max(case when code = 'bit2' then 1 else 0 end) ||
        max(case when code = 'bit3' then 1 else 0 end) ||
        max(case when code = 'bit4' then 1 else 0 end) ||
        max(case when code = 'bit5' then 1 else 0 end) ||
        max(case when code = 'bit6' then 1 else 0 end) ||
        max(case when code = 'bit7' then 1 else 0 end)
       )
from table t
group by id, unit;
```

And here is the method with the result as an integer:

```
select id, unit,
       (max(case when code = 'bit0' then 1 else 0 end) +
        max(case when code = 'bit1' then 2 else 0 end) +
        max(case when code = 'bit2' then 4 else 0 end) +
        max(case when code = 'bit3' then 8 else 0 end) +
        max(case when code = 'bit4' then 16 else 0 end) +
        max(case when code = 'bit5' then 32 else 0 end) +
        max(case when code = 'bit6' then 64 else 0 end) +
        max(case when code = 'bit7' then 128 else 0 end)
       )
from table t
group by id, unit;
```

You can see the latter work [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24742) at SQL Fiddle.

Comment: ORA-00905 : Missing Keywork -- ["<<"  highlighted]  :(

Comment: Just replace the values with 1, 2, 4, ..., 128.

Comment: Replaced them but the same error persists. Am I missing something? :(

Comment: @Dalek . . . I was looking at documentation for the wrong Oracle product.  It is not the database that supports `<<`, so I just put in constants.